# 'page_posts_impressions' and other 'Page Posts' insight for Facebook Page does not work with fql

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

`https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select object_id, metric, value from insights where metric in ('page_posts_impressions_unique') and object_id = OBJECT_ID and end_time = 1272351600 and period = period('day')`

The above returns empty array, while `https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/insights/page_posts_impressions_unique` returns data.

It seems none of the 'Page Posts' works with fql, however other insights like 'Page Impressions', 'Page Engagement` work fine.

What am I doing wrong here? Wrong `period` or `end_time`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `end_time` needs to set to 12AM PST/PDT (depending on daylights saving time) unix time exactly or the query returns empty. Example: 1330588800

Edit: Switched to '/insights' and passing 'since' parameter, timing not as strict here.